# Is it possible to add a voice dictation (mic icon) button to UISearchBar in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, ios13, voice

In iOS 13, Apple's own apps include mic buttons in search bars (for example, see attached image) that allow the user to begin voice dictation directly rather than having to first bring up the keyboard and start from there.

Is it possible to add the mic button to search bars in our apps, too? I cannot find any relevant API in `UISearchBar` or `UITextField` for this.

[image: App Store Connect search bar example]

Comment: Any Solution ?. Please share

Comment: iMessage has exactly what I want. Please help